# FadeIn and FadeOut issue

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function ($)

{
    $('.button-submit').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();  
        $('.content-greeting').fadeIn(0.1)
        $('.content-sayhi').fadeOut(0.1)
        $(this).addClass('active')
        $('.button-sayhi').removeClass('active')


    $('.button-sayhi').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        $('.content-sayhi').fadeIn(0.1)
        $('.content-about').fadeOut(0.1)
        $(this).addClass('active')
        $('.button-submit').removeClass('active')
    }):
    $('.button-about').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();  
        $('.content-about').fadeIn(0.1)
        $('.content-greeting').fadeOut(0.1)
        $(this).addClass('active')
        $('.button-about').removeClass('active')
    });
```

Hi guys, My code is working but, Everytime fadein and fadeout , divs goes top on eachother and jumping around. It doesnt fadein or fadeout correctly

Comment: Looks like you're missing `})` at the end of the first click function and at the end of `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed with adding .delay(500) to each fadeIn and fadeOut

Thanks anyway